# Exclude third party libraries from typescript build

Tags: angularjs, typescript, gulp

I want to exclude imported libraries from my result bundle. 
Lets say we have next code:

```
import * as angular from 'angular';
const app = angular.module('app',[]);
```

And we have this build task.

```
function buildTs(compileOptions) {
    browserify(compileOptions)
        .plugin(tsify, tsconfig.compileOptions)
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dest.js));
}
```

**When build will be finished, Angular lib will be included into bundle.js.
Can I avoid this?**

My tsConfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "types": [
      "angular",
      "angular-cookies",
      "angular-ui-bootstrap",
      "angular-ui-router",
      "jasmine",
      "angular-mocks"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "app"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Removing types from types not helps :)

Comment: Hi, As both `angular` and `angularjs` tags are different. I request to please remove either of the tag which is unnecessary. tag `angular` is for Angular 2/4 (strictly) and `angularjs` for Angular 1.x. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will make browserify ignore angularjs , and then it can be added from index.html .

```
var browserify = require("browserify")

browserify()
.ignore('angular')
```

---

> Any option to include several files without adding `.ignore(name)` each time? With array or smth like this?

```
var tsProject = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json');
gulp.task('scripts', function() { 
    var tsResult = gulp.src("lib/**/*.ts") 

    // or 
    tsProject.src() 
      .pipe(tsProject()); 

    return tsResult.js.pipe(gulp.dest('release'));
});
```

Thus , this might be a cleaner way to build Typescript files. In src , you can provide your own list of regular expression src files .

Comment: Seems working. Any option to include several files without adding .ignore(name) each time? With array or smth like this?

Comment: var tsProject = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json');
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    var tsResult = gulp.src("lib/**/*.ts") // or tsProject.src() 
        .pipe(tsProject());
 
    return tsResult.js.pipe(gulp.dest('release'));
});



_____________________________________

Thus , this might be a cleaner way to build Typescript files.
In src , you can provide your own list of regular expression src files .